# Нужна ли запятая после вводного слова "ну"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после вводного слова "ну"? И в каких случаях?

Answer (score 4):

НУ является частицей или междометием.

Междометия  выражают чувства, не называя их;  они выделяются паузой в устной речи и запятой (восклицательным знаком)  на письме. Междометие НУ выражает побуждение к действию, в частности к ответу: Ну, стреляй же!   Ну, что же молчишь?

Частицы  относятся к различным частям речи: они усиливают эмоциональность сообщения, произносятся без паузы и ударения и не выделяются на письме запятой. Частица НУ  выражает побуждение к действию, а также удивление, восхищение, негодование: Ну бал! Ну Фамусов! Ну как не порадеть родному человечку! Бабушка, ну расскажи сказку!   Ну что же, продолжайте.

В некоторых случаях используется авторское решение, зависящее от наличия паузы: Ну, и что дальше? Ну и что дальше?